# listing all available languages in android apps

Tags: android

i've been searching a for a while but couldn't find anything similar to what i'd need. I'd like to know how  i can list all languages available in an android application? and say, pick one of them to run as default.

Comment: The picked language should run as default on only that application or on the phone ?

Comment: the application only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a preferences Activity in your application and display all the supporting languages within it (may be in a list view with a check mark or something), when the user selects a specific language, just save the selected language preference in your Application Shared Preference.
Within every activity of your Application just run a conditional flow and use the Application's Drawables and String values with respect to the language selected in the Application Preference.

**EDIT**
Here is a good example of Localization
http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/android-application-localization-tutorial/
Since you don't want to check the selected language in the phone's settings, but only in the Application's context, then you should create a Preferences Activity specific to your Application. Here is a good Example of saving creating and using Preferences :
http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/android-preferences/

After doing that, just run a conditional flow in your Application's Activities, for example:

```
Class myActivity extends Activity
{
String KEY_SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "selected_language";
onCreate(...)
{
if(getApplicationContext().getSharedPrefrences().getString(KEY_SELECTED_LANGUAGE,"").equalsIgnoreCase("en"))
 {
  //change all the drawable/String values displayed in your activity to the version of the selected language.
 }
}
```